# Is there a Python code to pull information from Bitbucket?

Tags: python, bitbucket

I would need information such as drawing number, all commit requests, all pull requests, who created it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `atlassian-python-api` package, BitBucket module: https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/bitbucket.html

for example you can extract commits by this line of code:

```
bitbucket.get_commits(project, repository, hash_oldest, hash_newest, limit=99999)
```

Comment: I attempted to use this but I was confused for what to put (ie: project, repository, etc). Would it be id or uuid

Comment: @davidk3698 you either read the documentation if available or just try it out and see what works with what input. And what uuid are you talking about, there are rarely any uuids in atlassian products.

Comment: The project key is the string that is used as the abbreviation. Also is present in bitbucket project URL.